# Cryptocode package: dashed arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, cryptocode

I'd like to add a dashed arrow for the one annoted `c` in this drawing:

[image]

However, I can't find how to do, the `style` property does not work apparently for this kind of arrow...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [
n,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{bbrenv}{A}
  \begin{bbrbox}[name=A]

  \end{bbrbox}
  \bbrmsgto{top=$a$}
  \bbrmsgfrom{top={$b$}}
  % \bbrqryfrom{top={$c$}, style={dashed}}
  \bbrqryfrom{top={$c$}}
\end{bbrenv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `edgestyle=dashed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [
n,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{bbrenv}{A}
  \begin{bbrbox}[name=A]

  \end{bbrbox}
  \bbrmsgto{top=$a$}
  \bbrmsgfrom{top={$b$}}
  \bbrqryfrom{top={$c$},edgestyle=dashed}
  \bbrqryfrom{top={$c$}}
\end{bbrenv}
\end{document}
```

[image]